# Using Swift Closure. Recursive?

Tags: swift, closures

I just have a quick conceptual question about this closure here:

```
func getRandomUser(onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {

    let route = baseURL

    makeHTTPGetRequest(route, onCompletion: { json, err in

        onCompletion(json)

    })

}
```

What does the line onCompletion(json) do exactly? Is this a recursive call to onCompletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your function line-by-line:

```
1. func getRandomUser(onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {
2.     let route = baseURL
3.     makeHTTPGetRequest(route, onCompletion: { json, err in
4.         onCompletion(json)
5.     })
6. }
```

**Line 1**: this gives the signature of your function; it takes one argument, and that argument is of type `(JSON) -> Void`, which means the argument it accepts is a closure that itself takes one argument of type `JSON` and does not have a return value, i.e. "returns Void", `-> Void` or `-> ()`; note that the function definition also includes a local parameter name for that argument: within the function body, that closure is assigned to the constant `onCompletion`

**Line 2**: constant assignment...

**Line 3**: this calls the function `makeHTTPGetRequest(_:onCompletion:)`, which takes two arguments: a route (which does not use an external label in the call, hence the `_` in the function name as given previously), and a closure - this closure is of type `(JSON, NSError?) -> Void`; note that on this line where `onCompletion` occurs, this is the external label required for the second argument when calling the `makeHTTPGetRequest(_:onCompletion:)` function, there is not any assignment taking place (as occurred on **Line 1**)

**Line 4**: the closure assigned to the constant `onCompletion` is called with one argument...

So while it may be confusing that the text `onCompletion` occurs twice in this section of code (before the closure is actually invoked on Line 4), there is only one constant that goes by that name - the other occurrence is simply an external label for an argument.

If it helps at all, we can actually eliminate the use of the `onCompletion` label altogether by taking advantage of Swift's ["trailing closure syntax"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102) and rewrite it like so:

```
func getRandomUser(onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {
    let route = baseURL
    makeHTTPGetRequest(route) { json, err in onCompletion(json) }
}
```

...but that's a topic for another post  :)

Answer (score 1):

The `onCompletion` parameter of `makeHTTPGetRequest` is not available in its own scope. It's basically declaring what `onCompletion` is. It would then be calling `onCompletion` on `getRandomUser`.